# Insert root level directory for all image requests

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am working on a site migration and I need to set up some redirects for image files. Certain image path requests will come in to root-level subdirectories 
and I need to put `/new_directory/` as the first directory for all of them, like so:

```
Old site request -> new request
website.com/dir1/image.png -> website.com/new_directory/dir2/subdir1/image.gif
website.com/dir2/subdir1/image.gif -> website.com/new_directory/dir2/subdir1/image.gif
```

Here's what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to be working. What am I missing?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REQUESTURI} (dir1|dir2|dir3)(.+?)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)    [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REQUESTURI} (dir4|dir5|dir6)(.+?)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)    [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REQUESTURI} (dir7|dir8|dir9)(.+?)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)$  /new_directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have several `RewriteCond` lines broken up because my actual list of directories is quite long, and I want the rules to fit on one screen width.

Comment: Was there a copy-paste error in the first sample redirection, or is that actually the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me; make sure that you have `RewriteEngine on`, otherwise redirects won't be processed.  If you want to see whether or not `mod_rewrite` is being hit at all, use the `RewriteLog`:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

If you receive NO output whatsoever after a restart, `mod_rewrite` hasn't even been enabled.

Additionally, you can simplify your code like so:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir[1-9]/.+\./(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /new_directory/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will do the same as yours, except:

- It will no longer match `/some/other/dir1/image.gif`, `/dir1/jagif`, or `/dir1isagif`.
- Redirected URLs will no longer contain double slashes: `/new_directory//dir1/image.gif`.
- You no longer need to worry about greedy or non-greedy searches.

Let me know if I misunderstood your question!

Answer (score 0):

Go there to test your regexp http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (of course check "ereg" box)

Then here's your optimized (and tested through the previous site) RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REQUESTURI} (dir(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9))(.*)\.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)$
RewriteRule (.*)  /new_directory%3\.%4 [R=301,L]
```

For you information, %3 and %4 are what is extracted from RewriteCond (= you ignore the (.*) in the RewriteRule). Example: with URI "/subrep1/subrep2/mypic.jpg":

Substrings extracted:

```
%1 = dir1
%2 = 1
%3 = /subrep1/subrep2/mypic
%4 = jpg
```

Then in the RewriteRule it will be transformed to:

```
RewriteRule (.*)  /new_directory%3\.%4 [R=301,L]
```

Thus

```
/new_directory/subrep1/subrep2/mypic.jpg
```